# How to create an Instance from a queryset in Django?

Tags: django, view, django-queryset

I have the following View Code:

```
        n = Nutrients.objects.all()

        for q in n:
            q.save()
            Nutrition_Data.objects.create(food = l, nutrients = q)
```

Nutrition_Data is an Intermediate Table.

In food I save the ID from request.Post Data.
Is there a better way to save the Queryset (in n) into the Intermediate Table?

Comment: I do not knwo why it didn't work at first. But the code without q.save works now too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this more efficiently (requires Django>=1.4):

```
n = Nutrients.objects.all()
to_save = []

for q in n:
    # q.save() absolute since you just queried the database so no need to save it again
    nutrient_data = Nutrition_Data(food=l,
                                   nutrients_id=q.pk)
    to_save.append(nutrient_data)

Nutrition_Data.objects.bulk_create(to_save)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the relationship between food and nutrients as a ManyToManyField. Then you can create the data in one go:

```
n = Nutrients.objects.all()
l.nutrients.add(*n)
```

Note that you can set `Nutrients_Data` as a `through` table on the relationship, but if you have no other fields on that table apart from the food and nutrients ForeignKeys, there's no point.

Comment: Thanks. But I get an error: Object has no attribute nutrients

Comment: Did you add the ManyToManyField on Food, pointing at Nutrients?